# Date Conversion - Year only

Tags: sql

How can I convert date from '2015-03-24 07:56:06.070' to '2015'? Prints the year only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This depends on the RDBMS that you are using

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, look up "DATE_FORMAT"

select DATE_FORMAT("2015-03-24 07:56:06.070", "%Y");

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standard functionality is extract:

```
select extract(year from datecol)
```

Most databases support:

```
select year(datecol)
```

Some databases have other methods, such as:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'YYYY')
```

Answer (score -1):

For Sql Server 2008, here is a simple solution:
SELECT LEFT ('2015-03-24 07:56:06.070' , 4),

Comment: That's an alternative that assumes that the value is a string, not a date

Comment: Thank you Lamak for pointing out I did not include converting date to string in my suggested solution.